# WPF - duplicating a stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic

i have this (a rough e.g):

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label .../>
        <TextBox .../>
        <Button Content="Add new input row" ... />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

pretty self explanatory, i want to add a new Horizontal StackPanel with every click on the button..

is that possible?

thank you!

Comment: Yes. Use an `ItemsPanel` for example, bind it to an `ObservableCollection`, use a `StackPanel` as content or a template and add items to the collection in your button's onclick event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this XAML above I will do like this:

In the click event handle of every button name "Add new input row", I mean you can use this event for all of buttons.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            StackPanel stkButtonParent = btn.Parent as StackPanel;
            StackPanel stkCover = stkButtonParent.Parent as StackPanel;
            StackPanel newRow = NewRow();
            stkCover.Children.Add(newRow);
        }

        private StackPanel NewRow() {
            StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
            stk.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Foreground = Brushes.Red; // some attribute
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Background = Brushes.Transparent; // some attribute
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = "Add new row";
            btn.Click += btn_Click;
            stk.Children.Add(lbl);
            stk.Children.Add(txt);
            stk.Children.Add(btn);
            return stk;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible try handling the event like this for example:

```
    // Create your StackPanel.
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    // Add controls to new StackPanel
    // Control con = new Control();
    // sp.Children.Add(con);

    // Add created control to a previously created (and named) container.
    myStackPanel.Children.Add(sp);
```

If you would like your StackPanel to contain some controls you can also add them to it here.

There is a way to do this via XamlReader as well, but I have never tried it.

Here is a link to a short article:

[arcanecode.com](http://arcanecode.com/2007/09/07/adding-wpf-controls-progrrammatically/)

Comment: your new `StackPanel` would be empty, but the OP wants some `StackPanel` with some existing controls on it.

Comment: @KingKing well he could write a method which creates new StackPanel with controls he want. However I don't see him mentioned that it has to contain any existing controls. Anyway I'm unable to help more as long as he doesn't provide more details.

Comment: obviously i will add controls to it :)

Comment: @AdamBensh that's not the way `WPF` does, of course if you want to add the same controls with the same layout to your new StackPanel, you should use some kind of `Template`, that's a very powerful feature of WPF.

Comment: @AdamBensh yeah, well it shouldn't be a problem at all just add the controls with every click, but yes if they should share some specific template or sth. you should use it.